# Can I pass variables from the Jenkins into the terraform vars.tf?

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I have a Terraform code in stage and the same code should be deployed in another env also.

The problem is I am passing the VPC ID, subnet IDs, load balancer DNS along with Listener ARN, Route53 Zone ID, etc. I have passed all these as variables from vars.tf. When the same Terraform code deploys in another env (which is in another AWS account) VPC IDs, subnets, load balancers... with Zone ID, everything will be changed. But I need to use only one Terraform code.

Is there any method that I can pass these variables into my Terraform from Jenkins at the time of deployment?

Comment: can you your jenkinsfile or a snippet at least?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different variables files (`.tfvars`) for that. For example, this could be a valid layout for your use case:

```
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── route53.tf
├── iam.tf
├── ec2.tf
├── ...
├── env
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── us-east-1
│   │       └── variables.tfvars
│   ├── pro
│   │   └── us-east-1
│   │       └── variables.tfvars
│   └── tst
│       └── us-east-1
│           └── variables.tfvars
```

With that structure is just a matter of specifying the `.tfvars` directory depending on the environment you're deploying into in your Jenkins pipeline, for example:

```
terraform plan --var-file=./env/${environment}/${region}/variables.tfvars
```

Where `environment` and `region` are variables you can set in your Jenkinsfile as per your desired criteria, such as branch name or other things.

Answer (score 0):

As per my personal experience. I would avoid hardcoding the tfvars as much as I can and drive the workflow through varible. So the pattern I followed was

modularised all the terraform resources called them for eg. "infra-modules" put them into git repo.

1. VPC, subnet, nat gateway , internet gateway -> network module
2. EC2 -> ec2 module
3. ECS -> ecs module
4. Lambda -> lambda module

Created another git repo named "infra" and within that repo created a folder for the project and under the project I create tf file for each resource. Something like below.

```
- my-project (folder)
     - main.tf -> will have provider details and back-end details
     - network.tf -> will call network module
     - ec2.tf -> will call ec2 module
     - lambda.tf -> will call lambda module
 - backend.tfvars
 - jenkinfile  : In jenkinsfile I created map for my account config and pass the variable to terrform plan through TF_VAR. 

TF_VAR_aws_account_id = "${myConfig[myEnv].accountId}"
```

and terraform call would be

```
terraform plan -var="env=$myEnv" -out=".$myEnv.plan"
```

The benefit of this pattern is that the hardcoding of the variable through tfvars is minimal within modules and resources, variables are managed at one place (jenkinsfile) and reusability of the terraform resources across different projects and accounts.